# Get Value from a Textbox and Display on notification bars that drop down from the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want when i inter text and click notification drop down from top of page and show what i type plus fix text

itry this but is not show in notification bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1><span>Form Input</span> Samples</h1>
<p>Intro/JavaScript</p>

<article class="regular">
<h2>Textbox</h2>

<label for="tbuser">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="tbuser" placeholder="Enter username" maxlength="10">

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click Me">

<p class="output" id="output1"></p>

<script>
const txt1 = document.getElementById('tbuser')
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
const out1 = document.getElementById('output1')

function fun1() {
    out1.innerHTML = txt1.value;
}

btn1.addEventListener('click',fun1);

</script>


</article>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: like this https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-aef3e5ec0a.gif

Answer (score 0):

That page you showed uses the [overHang.js library](https://github.com/paulkr/overHang.js/). You can also download it or use a CDN for the same effect.

```js
const txt1 = document.getElementById('tbuser')
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
const out1 = document.getElementById('output1')
let intvl;
function fun1() {
  clearTimeout(intvl);
  intvl = setTimeout(() => $("body").overhang({
    message: 'thank you ' + txt1.value,
    customClasses: 'overhang'
  }), 2000);
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', fun1);
```

```css
.overhang {
  width: 80% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/overhang@1.0.5/dist/overhang.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/overhang@1.0.5/dist/overhang.min.css" />
<article class="regular">
  <h2>Textbox</h2>
  <label for="tbuser">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tbuser" placeholder="Enter username" maxlength="10">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click Me">
  <p class="output" id="output1"></p>
</article>
```

Comment: can i add fix text allways is show + that input like this exomple

Comment: fix text in + what i enter in that input like this exomple thank you this what you type

Comment: @maria Can you please clarify what the expected result is now?

Comment: can i add fix text + wht i type in input like this image https://i.ibb.co/bvvtWk3/fix-text-test.jpg

Comment: like this    thank you + textinput    i want thank you allwas show in notification

Comment: thank unmitigated now can i make notification center not full width like 80%

Comment: @maria I've updated again, but please keep it to one question per post.

Comment: unmiltigated  pls last qusiton and thank you so mush can you make the notification bar wait like 2 secend  after i click the button not immediately display

Comment: @maria Okay, updated.

Comment: omg thank you is look like magic how you talk with this script haha pls i want add text next the button and that text have number 900000 $ or smal image icon  and evry time i click in button the text will decrease -10000   i know you can talk with this script i can even pay you